# Javascript and HTML - Getting value from a SPAN and Selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to Javascript programming. I would like to get the selected value from the list of values presented to the customer. I want to display this as a simple text saying, the selection was  from the options provided. Let me paste the code snippet

```
<span id="Step2" style="display:none">
<form>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Type of Customization</legend>
      <p>
         <label>Available Customization</label>
         <select id = "myCust">
           <option value = "1">New Dimension Table</option>
           <option value = "2">Add a Fact Table</option>
           <option value = "3">Completely New Form</option>
           <option value = "4">Edit an Old Form</option>
           <option value = "5">Others</option>
         </select>
      </p>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

so from the provided options, if the person chooses, say, "Completely New Form" I would like to display that into the HTML

I tried

```
document.getElementById("myCust")
```

but that won't work.

Comment: document.getElementById("myCust").value

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response. I tried the following but is not working

    <td id="FooterTableStep2" style="background-color:Silver">
                <script>
   function getCust() {
    var typeofCust = document.getElementById("myCust")
    var cust = typeofCust.options[typeofCust.selectedIndex].text;
     return cust;
     }
    </script>
     Selected Customization : getCust()   
    </td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getCust() {
    var typeofCust = document.getElementById("myCust");
    var cust = typeofCust.querySelector('option[value="'+typeofCust.value+'"]');

    document.getElementById('selected-customer').innerText=cust.innerText;
}

document.getElementById('myCust')
  .addEventListener('change', getCust)
```

```html
<div id="FooterTableStep2" style="background-color:Silver">
    Selected Customization : <span id="selected-customer"></span>
</div>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Type of Customization</legend>
        <p>
            <label>Available Customization</label>
            <select id="myCust">
                <option value="1">New Dimension Table</option>
                <option value="2">Add a Fact Table</option>
                <option value="3">Completely New Form</option>
                <option value="4">Edit an Old Form</option>
                <option value="5">Others</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

`getElementById` returns the actual [HTML element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

```
const selectEl = document.getElementById('myCust');
const customer = selectEl.value;
console.log(customer); // selected value
```

It's also worth noting that *most* elements can also query their children

```
const row = document.querySelector('td:nth-child(13)');
const selectEl = row.getElementById('some-id');
```

Updated to include your comment:

```
<td id="FooterTableStep2" style="background-color: silver;">
    Selected Customization: <span id="selected-customer"></span>
</td>

<script>
    function getCust() {
        var typeofCust = document.getElementById("myCust");
        var cust = typeofCust.querySelector('option[value="' + typeofCust.value + '"]');

        document.getElementById('selected-customer').innerText = cust.innerText;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian.. I tried the following but not working..
    
    <td id="FooterTableStep2" style="background-color:Silver"> 
     <script> 
   function getCust() 
   { 
   var typeofCust = document.getElementById("myCust") 
   var cust = typeofCust.options[typeofCust.selectedIndex].text; 
   return cust; 
} 
</script> 

Selected Customization : getCust() 
</td>

Comment: Updated my answer. It doesn't matter where the `script` tag lives, it should usually go right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: You can add a `change` listener to the `<select>` and call `getCust` on change.

Comment: Thanks once again. 
I tried to copy your code, but still i dont see the SELECTEDVALUE displayed

<td id="FooterTableStep2" style="background-color:Silver">
     Selected Customization :  <span id="selected-customer"></span>   
    </td> 
                <script>
     function getCust() {
     var typeofCust = document.getElementById("myCust");
     var cust = typeofCust.querySelector('option[value="' + typeofCust.value + '"]');
     console.log(cust)
     document.getElementById('selected-customer').innerText = cust.innerText;
     }
    </script>

Comment: Added a working code snippet. I used a div instead your `td` since I have no context on what you table structure looks like